# Appium iOS: Uninstall app and delete session

Tags: ios, automation, appium

**Background**:
I want to remove the user logging session after the tests so that whenever I kick off tests again it starts from Login Functionality. But as of now after `teardown()` functions i.e. after quitting the session (the appium driver) the user remains logged in.

I have tried reset options/caps mentioned on this page.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/

but no luck except `fullReset` but it takes a lot of time because it also shuts down the simulator completely.

**Question**: How can I delete/remove the login session from the iOS app without having a simulator restarted?

I am using

Appium version 1.16.0

Capabilities properties

```
appium.platformName=IOS
appium.platformVersion=9
appium.deviceName=iPhone 6s plus
appium.app=/Users/CR9972/Desktop/iOSDemo/demo.app
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can create the app session from the scratch using the `@BeforeMethod` and then unistall/remove the app using the `@AfterMethod`. This way, you would be having a complete new session every time your test case would start executing.
To remove the app in the `@AfterMethod`, you can use:

```
driver.resetApp("bundle id of the app");
```

And if the above command doesn't work then you can use:

```
driver.removeApp("bundle id of the app");
```

Comment: How to get the bundle id programmatically for iOS apps?

Comment: @paul bundle id is the same aa that of package name of the app. You must be using that to initiate your automation script. You can use the package name here as well.

Comment: No Sameer, I am not using package name. I am not aware that there is something as package name for iOS Automation. I have updated the capabilities I am using, this doesn't have package name.

Comment: @paul can you mention all the capabilities you are using in the question?

Comment: @paul you have used direct path of the app. Same you can use in the `remove`/`reset` method.

Comment: None of those are working. Are these working at your end for the iOS app?

Comment: I have a scenario in mid of the application I have to uninstall and install the application. Here how would we maintain the session, full reset and no reset does not help here